# 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found' when making python class

Tags: python, class, oop, elementtree

I'm trying to make a class which makes it easier to handle XML-invoices, but I am having trouble getting ElementTree to work within a class.

This is the general idea of what I'm trying to do:

```py
def open_invoice(input_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as invoice_file:
        return ET.parse(input_file).getroot()
```

This works fine, and I can make functions to handle the data without issue. But when trying to do the equivalent inside a class, I get an error message:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

I think this means that the parser is never given anything to parse, though I could be wrong.

The class:

```py
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class Peppol:

    def __init__(self, peppol_invoice):
        self.invoice = xmltodict.parse(
             peppol_invoice.read()
        )

        self.root = ET.parse(peppol_invoice).getroot()
```

Making the class instance:

```py
from pypeppol import Peppol

def open_invoice(input_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as invoice_file:
        return Peppol(invoice_file)

invoice = open_invoice('invoice.xml')
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are attempting to read the contents of the file `peppol_invoice` twice, once in the call to `xmltodict.parse`, and once in the call to `ET.parse`.

After the call to `peppol_invoice.read()` completes, `peppol_invoice` is left pointing at the end of the file.  You get the error in your question title because when `peppol_invoice` is passed to `ET.parse`, there is nothing left to be read from the file.

If you want to read the contents of the file again, call `peppol_invoice.seek(0)` to reset the pointer back to the start of the file:

```py
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class Peppol:

    def __init__(self, peppol_invoice):
        self.invoice = xmltodict.parse(
             peppol_invoice.read()
        )

        peppol_invoice.seek(0)     # add this line
        self.root = ET.parse(peppol_invoice).getroot()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `invoice.xml` is empty, does not contain XML or contains XML + over stuff before the XML data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('empty.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write('')
    # or
    # f.write('No xml here!')
with open('empty.xml') as f:
    ET.parse(f).getroot()

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: But the file isn't empty. The first bit of code works perfectly fine, and I can call functions and print data like you'd expect with a ET parsed xml file.

The issue I'm having is getting it to work within a class.

Comment: @r3d5un see the updated answer. It might also mean the file contains other stuff except for the xml data itself. I can't tell about other parts of your code, only about those you showed us